# How can I use the table name in a column alias in Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access, my table is:Exam{id,name}, and my query is

```
select Exam.id as 'Exam.id',Exam.name as 'Exam.name' from Exam
```

Now when I executed this query this error ocurred:

> "Exam.id" is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

I want to use the full table + column as the alias, Exam.name as 'Exam.name', but how can I get Access to accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error indicates, punctuation is not allowed in an alias in MS Access. Consider revising your query to eliminate punctuation.

```
select e.id as 'ExamId', 
    e.name as 'ExamName' 
from Exam e
```

Comment: it solved.it was because of dot.i removed dot from it's alias name: Exam.id as 'Exam/id'

Comment: Are there databases in which your preferred alias, Exam.ID, would actually work?

Comment: @David: It works in Oracle 10g. `select id as "Exam.Id" from MySchema.Exam`.